# Why does huggingsound Speech Recognition model output more probabilities than words or characters?

Tags: python, speech-recognition, huggingface-transformers

I have used a [hugging face model](https://huggingface.co/jonatasgrosman/wav2vec2-large-xlsr-53-spanish) to transcribe Spanish speech into text.

After transcribing an audio, I get an output of probabilities. Nevertheless, the number of elements in this list is way bigger than the total number of words or the total number of characters in each transcription. Hence, what does each probability represent?

Example:

```
audio_file  transcription   probabilities               n_words n_chars n_probabilities
0   1191045604182503424 ... [0.8018453121185303, ...]   265     1974    39331
1   1192339651618648064 ... [0.5861434936523438, ...]   243     1454    28877
2   1192530643797860352 ... [0.9996742010116577, ...]   153     902     17935
3   1192571268513566720 ... [0.7634865045547485, ...]   77      471     9357
4   1192910076517986304 ... [0.9717265367507935, ...]   20      200     3995
```

Answer (score 0):

It was just an error of the shape of probabilities, instead of a list of floating point numbers it provided a string of the list. Hence, the length of the probabilities was calculated as the length of the whole string. The answer to the question is: The probabilities are assigned to each character.